# Python's `imshow` hangs when I evaluate in console, but doesn't if I run the program

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, matplotlib, pycharm

I am using PyCharm, on MacOS, and using Python 2.7.6.

**The Problem:** If I run my program, the image displays just fine. If however, I *evaluate* the code on the console, a figure appears, but just sits there without anything displayed, and just gives me the spinning beach ball. Why is this occurring? Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

fileName = '/data_batch_1'

def unpickle(file):
    import pickle
    fo = open(file, 'rb')
    dict = pickle.load(fo)
    fo.close()
    return dict

dict = unpickle(fileName)
data = dict['data']
labels = dict['labels']

imageIndex = 0
image = data[imageIndex,:]
imageVol = np.zeros((32,32,3), 'uint8')
for ii in range(0,3,1):
    imageVol[:,:,ii] = image[(ii*1024) : (ii+1)*1024].reshape([32, 32])
pl.imshow(imageVol,interpolation='none')
pl.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried with a single image to see if `pl.show()` is working fine?

Comment: @dragon2fly How do you mean? What should I type into the console? Thanks

Comment: @Learnaholic - I'd guess that this has something to do with PyCharm's console not playing well with whatever matplotlib backend you're using.  Does the same thing happen if you use IPython as a console instead? (You should be able to use it from inside PyCharm, I think...)