# How to make a Python image 'fit' the figure?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, figure

I have a matrix that is `500x5000` in size, and I am trying to visualize it via matplotlib. Simply, I have:

```
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np
mat = np.random.rand(500,5000)
plt.imshow(mat, interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

The problem is that I get an image that is somewhat 'squeezed', as so:

[image]

I would just like to be able to make the image 'fit' the figure, so that I can inspect it better. Is there a way to do this in matplotlib?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like the image to adjust so that it fills up the available space, specify `aspect='auto'` to `imshow`. Note that the pixels will not be square!

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
mat = np.random.rand(500,5000)
plt.imshow(mat, interpolation='none', aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Just for comparison, the default behavior forces the pixels to be square, resulting is something more like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Joe. I have accepted your answer. By the by... would you be willing to help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996102/pythons-imshow-hangs-when-i-evaluate-in-console-but-doesnt-if-i-run-the-pro?noredirect=1#comment44696124_27996102)? Many advanced thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`set_aspect`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect) method on the current axes. In your case, the aspect ratio is about 1:10, so you could set it to 10 to get a square image:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mat = np.random.rand(500,5000)
plt.imshow(mat, interpolation='none')

plt.gca().set_aspect(10)
plt.show()
```